# How to terminate a php server script while it is waiting for a reply from a php client script?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, client

Currently I have a setInterval javascript function which calls an ajax function to call a php script. This php script is a server that is waiting for a request from a client being run by another program. The client will send a String whenever there are changes made and this string  is to be echoed back through ajax.

```
setInterval(function(){getTopo()}, 2000);
```

`getTopo()` is a $.ajax calling server.php

I want to terminate the server.php file if there is no reply within 2 secs before running getTopo() again.

Else can I output through ajax an echo in the php's while loop?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Save the interval into a variable, for example:

`var t = setInterval(getTopo, 2000)`

And use `clearInterval(t)` to stop querying the server.

From here, you should create your own code to satisfy your needs.